# Why is my transaction not rolledback by spring annotations?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

I am at my wits end trying to debug this issue. Basically, I have a mvc application where I have a `BusinessManagerImpl` class which has 2 DAOs (`UserDao` and `ProductDao`) and am using JDBC with a connection pool instead of an ORM. Database is mySQL with InnoDb engine. `RestUserController` is the calling class of `BusinessManagerImpl`.

`BusinessManagerImpl.addUser()` has been annotated with `@Transactional` annotation. I have also tried annotating `@Transactional` at the class level but doesn't seem to make a difference. Both DAOs are also annotated as such.

`BusinessManagerImpl.addUser()` uses `UserDao` to insert a user but a subsequent call to `ProductDao.getAllProducts()` throws a `RuntimeException` on purpose to cause the transaction to rollback. My expectation is that the user should not have been inserted as a `RuntimeException` has occurred and the transaction would have been rolledback but I have checked my database and the new user is inserted.

I have tried with throwing a checked exception and using the "rollback for" parameter of `@Transactional` annotation but it doesn't work. I have also tried different values of propagation like `Propagation.Required` but doesn't seem to have an effect on rolling back the transaction. I have tried searching on stackoverflow and google but came up with nothing that could help. Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong or missing something? Thank you. Below is my setup:

application-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="someproject" />
<!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="yyy" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

BusinessManagerImpl class

```
@Service 
public class BusinessManagerImpl implements BusinessManager{

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
private ProductDao productDao;
....
@Override   
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public User addUser(User user) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    User tempUser = userDao.addUser(user);
    productDao.getAllProducts();

    return tempUser;
}
```

UserDaoImpl class

```
@Service
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public UserDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    super();
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}   

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}       

private JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    return jdbcTemplate;
}       
...
    @Override   
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
public User addUser(final User user) {
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    final String sql = "insert into user (username, password) "
            + " VALUES (?, ?)";

    getJdbcTemplate().update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            int index = 1;              

            ps.setString(index++, user.getUsername());
            ps.setString(index++, user.getPassword());


            return ps;
        }
    }, holder);

    int seq = holder.getKey().intValue();
    user.setSeq(seq);
    return user;
}
```

ProductDaoImpl class

```
@Service
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public ProductDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    super();
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}   

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}   

@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
public List<Product> getAllProducts() throws Exception {

    if(true)
        throw new RuntimeException("on purpose");

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    List<Product> products = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select * from product",
            new ProductRowMapper());

    return products;
}
```

RestUserController class

```
@RestController
public class RestUserController {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestUserController.class);

@Autowired
private BusinessManager businessManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> createEmployee(@RequestBody User user) 
{
    logger.debug("adding user:"+user);
    User addedUser=null;
    try {
        addedUser = businessManager.addUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity(addedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

}
```

web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml  
        </param-value>
        </context-param>
          <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
          </listener>
          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```

spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="someproject" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Comment: Which application server do you use?

Comment: Just tomcat. There is no config in tomcat, application was deployed as a war in an external tomcat

Comment: Let me guess you have a configuration xml that is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, which also contains `<context:component-scan base-package="someproject" />`...

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, you are right, I do have that in my spring-web-context.xml. I have updated my question to include the web.xml and the spring-web-context.xml. However, your comment got me thinking so I decided to change the base-package to <context:component-scan base-package="someproject.controller" /> in my spring-web-context.xml, where my controllers reside in but I still kept the web.xml as it is and the transaction management worked!

Comment: I have also experimented excluding the snippet above from web.xml but got a bunch of autowiring stacktraces from spring so obviously the exclusion was not right. I am not 100% sure but I don't seem to have come across in books on how to set things up for this kind of scenario. I can only assume that you must have encountered this situation before. Do you know how come spring was not able to reconcile both component scans in spring-web-context.xml and application-context.xml?

Comment: Regardless, thanks to all who responded but especially so to M. Deinum who managed to solve this mystery for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I find use of @Service annotation on Dao Implementation class weird. Try replacing them with @Repository and adding `rollbackFor = {Exception.class}` to all of your transactional annotations.

Comment: Thanks but I do recall using @Repository as well but same results. Will give your suggestion a try again with the rollbackFor parameter and post the results here.

Comment: Ok, I have tried what you suggested but my user is still inserted into the database :(

Comment: Thanks ritesh.garg for your input.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2 application contexts configs, you have to specify the base-package differently. Do not let the web application context scan DAO package.

Comment: How this changes the observed behaviour?

Comment: Thanks user29637. To answer Nikem's question, the user that was meant to be inserted was not inserted when the exception was thrown in productDao and base-package was specified to be just "someproject.controller"